# Getting html table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I can't seem to be able to get the row data from the table on this page: https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory?locale=en

Here's my code:

```
url = requests.get('https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory?locale=en')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={"id": "companiesListTable"})
tables
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The data is loaded dynamically, so get it from the API directly. Check the network connections for the API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Table you are looking for its dynamically loaded so you can call endpoint from Network Tab

***How to find:***

Go to chrome developer mode find Network tab and reload website also you can find data copy paste data in search also and in the last URL containing your data as in `json` format.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = requests.get('https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Tx8nD0MLIy8DTyMXAwczVy9vV2cTY0MnEz1w8EKjIycLQwtTQx8DHzMDYEK3A08A31NjA0CjfWjSNLv7ulnbuAY6OgR5hYWYgzUQpl-AxPi9BvgAI4GhPVHgZXgCwFUBVi8iFcByA9gBXgcWZAbGhoaYZDpma6oCABqndOv/p0/IZ7_NHLCH082KOAG20A6BDUU6K3082=CZ6_NHLCH082K0H2D0A6EKKDC520B5=N/?sectorID=All&_=1630218635227')
main_data=url.json()['data']
df=pd.DataFrame(main_data)
```

**Outptut:**

```
symbol       lonaName                            shortName  Acronym  isinCode
0   1330    Abdullah A. M. Al-Khodari Sons Co.  ALKHODARI   ALKHODARI   SA12L0O0KP12
1   4001    Abdullah Al Othaim Markets Co.  A.OTHAIM MARKET A.OTHAIM MARKET SA1230K1UGH7
....
```

**Image [*in left hand side you can find data that generates URL by searching*]:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
url = requests.get('https://www.saudiexchange.sa/tadawul.eportal.theme.helper/ThemeSearchUtilityServlet')
pprint(url.json())
```

The row data table can be extracted directly using this API.